# Error 521 on Debian but not on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, debian, apache-2.4

I was using Ubuntu 17 before and now I switch to Debian 8 and reuploaded my website and now im getting 521 Error WebServer Down. 
Im using CloudFlare, Apache 2.4.10, my website is php.

PS: If you need my Apache config just ask!

Answer (score 0):

Please check that the server is up, running and accepting Cloudfare accesses.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

521 occurs when either your web server refuses connection from cloudflare and blocks access to port 80 or 443, or web service isn't running.

- Check your Apache server is up and running in the above mentioned ports. You can check if your server is responding by running a curl against your server IP. If curl returns "HTTP 200" it is running, if it returns "connection refused" it isn't running.
- Make sure you are not blocking CF IPs in .httaccess, iptables, or firewall of your server.

Comment: Well my apache2 is running I don't get any error when it start there is not error log. So what is wrong!

Comment: did you figure it out? I am struggling with same problem since yesterday.